# toggle button to resize div

Tags: javascript, css, angular, iframe

I would like to create a clickable icon in which once i click on it i will be able to change the size of a div to make it full size for the browser. This is what i have for html and wanted to know what possible ways to handle this functionality.

```
<div>
    <a (click)="onResize($event)" class="icon-resize"></a>
</div>
```

the html that i would like to expand is:

```
<div id="editview">
        <iframe id="editFrame"></ifram>
</div>

public onResize(event:any) {
        event.target.innerWidth;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want screen full Windows with ifram you can use anmation with angular.
try Watch :
https://coursetro.com/posts/code/63/Angular-4-Animation-Tutorial
with animtation triger you can apply css width:100% for full screen

Comment: very nice to try - good to know , Thanks! But currently i just want a simple and basic way of toggling the div of the iframe.